# Add a tool to dropdown menu with the Python Add-In Wizard

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, python-addin

Is it possible to add a tool created with the Python Add-In wizard to a menu in a toolbar that is also created with the add-in wizard?

I haven't had much luck in trying to figure this out.  I've searched around the internet/StackExchange and have not came up with anything.  Below is an example of what I'm trying to do.

I'm tyring to move the tool in the picture into the Tools dropdown menu

[image]

Here are the options I have when I right click on a menu

[image]

Here are the options I have when i right click on the toolbar.

[image]

Is it possible to edit the config.xml file and move the tool into a menu?

Comment: There is an add image button you can use when you are asking/editing your question.  Please use that to embed your images rather than linking to them.  6th button from the left in the [edit] screen.

Comment: Thanks for the help on inserting images.  Its much clearer now!

Comment: Based on the second answer in this [question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93825/how-to-store-python-add-in-menu-customization-configuration-in-esriaddin-file) I might be able to do this by customizing the config.xml tool.  I'll give it a try next Monday hope it doesn't break!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to change the layout of the toolbar by modifying the config.xml file that's created using the Python Addin Assistant (PAA). I was clued into this based on the second answer from this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93825/how-to-store-python-add-in-menu-customization-configuration-in-esriaddin-file).

[image]

In the picture below, I had to move the crossed out line to the menu group called *Tools*.  I recommend to edit the format of the .xml document so you can easily view the structure of the tool and modify the layout as needed.

[image]

After making the edit to the config.xml, you will need to run the *makeaddin.py* script so the changes "stick".  I'm not sure if the config file stays intact after new features are added to the toolbar through PAA (new features include buttons, menu's or tools).  It may be overwritten meaning you will have to go back and manually modify the config file. Currently, this approach is the only way to make edits to the layout and to add a **Tool** to a menu.

**--UPDATE--**

I added some additional buttons/menus since posting this question and the config.xml file does indeed stay intact.  It's a shame you can't rearrange the ordering of your toolbar through PAA but at least this is possible by manually modifying the config.xml file.